# Need a traceable id for each outbound request

Tags: http, identity, w3c

I guess I am having way too many ids in a request log and I just need one more. What I already have:

1. User-Id to identify who the user is
2. Session-Id to identify the same active session
3. Correlation-Id to identify the single user action and subsequent actions originating from that action

What seems to be missing is a unique id for each of these subsequent actions. For example, a user sends a request along with a generated Correlation-Id, I then make some more outbound requests to other systems, they all have the same Correlation-Id as they are related from that inbound request. However, if one of these outbound requests fails in another system, I need to be able to trace back in my log that particular request, using some unique id obtained from another system log.

I wonder what is the common practice or even Internet standard about this id? What is it called? Is it a random one? Or just append a sequence number after the Correlation-Id? And How is it done? Do I generate it along with the outbound request? Or the other system generates one and attach it in the outbound response?

Note I am asking about some standard so this is not an open question.

Comment: Even if there is a standard, there probably isn't only one, but any number of homecooked-come-standard solutions. Which isn't really any more focused.